# find out what app/package uses sensor

Tags: adb, logging, sensors, proximity-sensor

on my device running AOSP something accesses a sensor of my phone continuously, preventing it from going into deep sleep and thus draining battery.

Logcat shows the pid, but that just links to android.hardware.sensors@2.1-service.multihal.odin (using adb and ps -p PID)

an entry in logcat looks like this:

```
10-10 21:33:18.615   869   954 I android.hardware.sensors@2.1-service.multihal.odin: MIUS:isWakeUpSensor()
10-10 21:33:18.617   869   954 I android.hardware.sensors@2.1-service.multihal.odin: MIUS:run() after post event here
10-10 21:33:18.817   869   954 I android.hardware.sensors@2.1-service.multihal.odin: MIUS:run() before post event here
10-10 21:33:18.817   869   954 I android.hardware.sensors@2.1-service.multihal.odin: MIUS:readEvents() enter
10-10 21:33:18.817   869   954 I android.hardware.sensors@2.1-service.multihal.odin: MIUS: before polling
10-10 21:33:19.068   869   954 I android.hardware.sensors@2.1-service.multihal.odin: MIUS: poll result timeout, continue for next
10-10 21:33:19.068   869   954 I android.hardware.sensors@2.1-service.multihal.odin: MIUS:readEvents() exit
```

Is there any way to find out what actually calls the sensor?
Thanks in advance!